# Typing with a right-to-left language on Windows Vista Home Premium (English)

Tags: keyboard-layout, input-languages

A friend's laptop came with "Windows Vista Home Premium (SP1)" installed in English.

But she's from a country with a right-to-left language, and she wants to be able to type in her own language from right-to-left.

Going to the control panel and adding a keyboard on her language did half of the trick. She can type in her language but on a left-to-right way.

Is it possible to enable the cursor to go on the other direction?

Comment: This would be a per-application feature. What applications would she like to type RtL in?

Comment: It's possible in word processors like MSWord, etc. etc. where it's supported, but as MarkM said it's application dependent.

Comment: It would be mainly on Adobe Photoshop CS4.

Comment: We looked for this last year: http://superuser.com/questions/20187.  If it's Arabic, there's a special plugin for Photoshop.

Comment: I believe in Photoshop CS4 rtl typing is supported but... I have no idea how to implement it.